# Display a Form in front of another Form that is always at the top

Tags: forms, delphi

I have a Form that stay always on top with **FormStyle -> fsStayOnTop**, and I did another Form with this same settings. But when I show this other Form, it is showed always behind, and not in front of first Form. So, how I do to the second Form be displayed in front of the first Form?

Comment: Seems, there is no place On Top for more than one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An owned top level window always appears above its owner. So, make the `fsStayOnTop` form be the owner of the other form. In VCL terms, that means setting the `PopupMode` property to `pmExplicit`, and assigning the `PopupParent` property.

```
OtherForm.PopupMode := pmExplicit;
OtherForm.PopupParent := AlwaysOnTopForm;
OtherForm.Show;
```

Comment: could you please tell me what is the Unit for AlwaysOnTopForm ?

Comment: @kish That variable represents the form described in the question as being always on top.